# How to install dependency into package folder?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a following folder structure:

```
- root/
     - app/
     - src/
     - node_modules/
```

I published some package on npmjs and in the moment when i type in /root folder `npm install my_package -S` dependency my_package installs in root folder node_modules and i would like to install them in the package folder ie node_modules/my_package /node_modules

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cycles are handled using the property of node's module system that it walks up the directories looking for node_modules folders. So, at every stage, if a package is already installed in an ancestor node_modules folder, then it is not installed at the current location.

[-npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#tl-dr)